# How to force Wi-Fi to rescan available sources and reconnect to a fixed named source from crontab?

Tags: network, wifi, router, cron

I have a server computer running macOS and sometimes is using Wi-Fi only in evenings. The room's router supporting the Wi-Fi source is set to automatically reboot weekly. So when that happens, the Wi-Fi source disappears for a few minutes, and sometimes I find that the server by itself is not able to automatically reconnect to it when the router becomes normal again. I'm thinking adding a cron job to force the server to rescan available Wi-Fi signals and try to reconnect to it if it find the named source.